# Adding a feature class to the current ArcGIS Pro map with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, feature-class, addlayer

I wrote some simple code that created multiple polygons using the Buffer tool.
I will use it in a toolbox and therefore want the outFeatureClass to be automatically added to the current map.

The following code doesn't work. "outcome" is the outFeatureClass I want to add.

```py
pw = r"C:\Users\Main\GIS\Data\ArcGISProject\ArcGISProject.gdb\outcome"
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
aprxMap = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]
aprxMap.addLayer(pw)
```

Running the code in the ArcGIS Pro Python command line I receive an error:

```
 "ValueError: r"C:\Users\Main\GIS\Data\ArcGISProject\ArcGISProject.gdb\outcome"
```

The `env.workspace` for the Python file is set to `r"C:\Users\Main\GIS\Data\ArcGISProject\ArcGISProject.gdb"`.

Comment: What is the full error message including line number?  If you have set arcpy.env.workspace then that should be part of the code snippet that you present.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the help file on the [addLayer()](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/map-class.htm#) method for a map it takes a "Layer or LayerFile object". You have passed in `pw` which is a string which happens to represent a path to a Feature Class, so not a *Layer Object*. ArcGIS Pro wants you to access a dataset via a layer file but as you are directly accessing the FeatureClass I assume a lyrx file does not exist.

You create a Layer object using the MakeFeatureLayer tool.

This is what you can do in ArcGIS Pro 2.6:

```py
with arcpy.EnvManager(addOutputsToMap=True):
  pw = r"C:\Users\Main\GIS\Data\ArcGISProject\ArcGISProject.gdb\outcome"
  arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(pw,"Outcome")
```

Comment: Thanks. This works fine when running the code in the ArcGIS Pro Python command line. When I run it in a toolbox it doesn't work although there is no error message.